# clustering companies based on several time series variables in SAS

Tags: sas, statistics, time-series, cluster-analysis

I have around 70 companies that I would like to cluster into smaller groups based on three time series variables using SAS.

The data is standardized and stacked. It looks like this:

```
Day  Company  Var1  Var2  Var3
1       A     0.01  0.015 0.14
2       A      ...
3       A      ...
...
99      Z      ...
100     Z      ...
```

Here are my thoughts:

1. I combine the three variables into one variable by calculating their Euclidean distance Var4

Then I will unstack the data and get a new dataset like this:

```
Day  Var4_A  Var4_B ... Var4_Z
1    0.141    0.1   ...  0.23
2        
...
99   
100
```

2. I send the new dataset to proc similarity to get some sort of similarity 
   matrix
3. I send the similarity matrix to proc cluster and get the company groups

My question is:

Is step 1 a sensible approach to combine the three variables? I have found some examples online that use step 2 and 3 to cluster time series data, but they seem to use only 1 variable.

Comment: Have you considered using any of the built-in cluster analysis procedures, e.g. `proc fastclus` or `proc modeclus` ?

Comment: @user667489 In my understanding, fastclus clusters the observations, not the companies thou, is that correct? I don't want different observations from the same company to fall into different groups. Is this doable through fastclus?

Comment: I would consider running a separate cluster analysis for each indivdual day, or grouping adjacent days together and taking the mean values of var1-varn before running the analysis for each time period using by-group processing.

Comment: @user667489 this makes sense- after running cluster on each day, how do I arrive at ONE final result for future use?

Comment: There are many possible ways - it's a matter of choosing one that works for you. E.g. you could look at how often pairs of companies are placed together in the same cluster across all the separate analyses and put them in the same final cluster if this number exceeds a certain threshold.

Comment: Another approach would be to run a single analysis with time as an additional dimension, allow each company to be assigned to multiple different clusters at different times, and to generate your final set of clusters, assign each company to the cluster in which it appears the most frequently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual approach would be to use **dynamic time warping distance**. But you may not need this here, assuming there is no time delay between the companies.

Have you tried directly pivoting this data set into companies (then havong days x variables new variables) and using Euclidean distance on that?

Taking the Euclidean norm of all your variables does not sound like a good idea as feature reduction to me...